# Doctrine Performance boost by turning unneccessary features off

Tags: pdo, doctrine-1.2

I have some cron jobs that run php under cli, they create tons of new entities and save them.

My script was taking so long, so instead of using doctrine to save data (persist, then flush), I wrote some simple SQL insert commands and the performance was increased significantly, what used to take 15 seconds now takes 0.3 second.

Googling my way around I found this:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine-performance-revisited.html

So the article basically says doctrine does way more than PDO, since PDO does "No object creation, no hydration of objects from result rows, no identity management, no change tracking, nothing."

My project heavily relies on Doctrine, and I love it, but for some batch works it's really slow, I was wondering if there is a way to make doctrine not do any of the above mentioned nice things to do temporarily when you are dealing with tons of data.

In other words, is it possible to turn hydraction, identity management, change tracking and etc off sometimes? Or do you recommend that I continue to use SQL command where appropriate.